# Как я могу передать AJAX ответ между скриптами в chrome-extension?

Tags: jquery, ajax, chrome-extension

Не получаеться передать ответ AJAX между скриптами в chrome-extension. Есть 2 файла со скриптами,файл `main.js`  подключается к текущей вкладки и передает `tab_url`  в `background.js`   и может получить ответ `bacMsg`.

//main.js

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage('qwer', function(backMsg){
 $('.fullListenHero__title').append('<div class="soundTitle_drobo">
<a href="'+backMsg+'">Download</a></div>');
});
```

//background.js

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, link,myCallback){

var curl = false;

function setUrl(){ 
  return $.ajax({
      url: 'http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=https://soundcloud.com/travisscott-2/wonderful-ftthe-weeknd&client_id=e18f93a6aaaf77192fa6f6180f294feb',
      dataType: 'json',
      // async:false,
      success: function (data){
      curl = data.id;
       }
  });}
  setUrl().done(myCallback(curl));  // myCallback отправляет в main.js
 });
```

Как мне отправить данные полученные в AJAX запросе ? Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что обработчики событий `chrome.extension.onMessage` по-умолчанию работают синхронно. 

Внутри тела вашей функции вы используете асинхронный код, о чем необходимо сообщить обработчику.

Согласно [документации](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging#simple):

> If you want to asynchronously use sendResponse, add `return true;` to the onMessage event handler.

Что говорит о том, что вам просто необходимо вернуть `true` в теле функции:

```js
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (request, link, myCallback) {

var curl = false;

    function setUrl() {
        return $.ajax({
            url: 'http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=https://soundcloud.com/travisscott-2/wonderful-ftthe-weeknd&client_id=e18f93a6aaaf77192fa6f6180f294feb',
            dataType: 'json',
            // async:false,
            success: function (data) {
                curl = data.id;
            }
        });
    }

    setUrl().done(myCallback(curl));  // myCallback отправляет в main.js

    return true; // <-- решает проблему
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)